# Read phantomjs command line options inside script

Tags: javascript, console, phantomjs

I start PhantomJS from command-line with option (rest of them are removed):

```
phantomjs --debug=false script.js
```

W would like to read `--debug` flag state inside script.js:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var debug = // init boolean value depends of flag --debug from console

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    if(debug) {
        console.log('Console:' + msg);
    }
};

// ...
```

Unfortunatety `system.args` doesn't contain command-line options.

Comment: I know there's a duplicate but I can't find it. Answer: no, it's not possible for every option, but for [some](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html).

Comment: I haven't found answer for that. I hope that it is possible more than [settings](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for google and did not find any useful hints.
And i know that phantomjs can not use npm modules
It is desperate.
phantomjs system module is not node system module, so npm package almost can not be compatible with phantomjs. Extremely frustrated, I can only write their own command line parsing parameters

Create a file commandLineArgs.js

```
module.exports = function (args, optionDefinitions) {
// via : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454087/read-phantomjs-command-line-options-inside-script
    var result = {
        args: [],
        options: {}
    };
    for (var j in optionDefinitions) {
        var def = optionDefinitions[j];
        if (def['multiple'] === true) {
            result.options[def['name']] = [];
        }
    }

    checkPoint_i:for (var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
        var arg = args[i];

        if (args[i].slice(0, 1) === "-") {

            var k = args[i].replace(/^-{1,2}/, '');

            for (var j in optionDefinitions) {
                var def = optionDefinitions[j];
                if (def['name'] === k || def['alias'] === k) {
                    i++;
                    if (def['multiple'] === true) {
                        result.options[def['name']].push(args[i]);
                    } else {
                        result.options[k] = args[i];
                    }
                    continue checkPoint_i;
                }
                // no def so change to args
            }

        }
        result.args.push(arg);
    }
    return result;
};
```

And then mark it in your code，Use it like this

```
var commandLineArgs = require('./node_modules/command-line-args');
var optionDefinitions = [
    {name: 'header', alias: 'H', type: String, multiple: true},
    {name: 'debug'},
];
var command = commandLineArgs(system.args, optionDefinitions);

console.log(command.options['header']); 
console.log(command.args);
```

run: `phantomjs yourSctipt.js --header "Host: google.com" --debug true http://www.google.com/`

```
// output [Host: google.com]
// output [http://www.google.com/]
```

Hope this can help you